# User Material-UI React Font Icons

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fonts, material-design

I want to use the [Material UI Font-Icons](https://material-ui.com/style/icons/#font-icons). On the website it says

> The Icon component will display an icon from any icon font that supports ligatures. As a prerequisite, you must include one, such as the Material icon font in your project, for instance, via Google Web Fonts:
>
> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">`
>
> Icon will set the correct class name for the Material icon font. For other fonts, you must supply the class name using the Icon component's className property.
>
> To use an icon simply wrap the icon name (font ligature) with the Icon component, for example:
>
> `<Icon>star</Icon>`
>
> By default, an Icon will inherit the current text color. Optionally, you can set the icon color using one of the theme color properties: primary, secondary, action, error & disabled.

I included the stylehsheet. I am not able to use the `<Icon />` component though because `<Icon />` is not defined. How do I import `<Icon />`?

Comment: you can install and `material-ui` and use `import { Icon } from "@material-ui/core";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon component needs to be imported as SGhaleb said, but I will add that some of the icons needed different imports. For instance, the school icon is imported like this `import SchoolIcon from '@material-ui/icons/School'` and called with `<SchoolIcon />`.

This may have or will change in the future to make it easier to import straight from @material-ui/icons like with the ExpandMore/ExpandLess icon `import { ExpandLess, ExpandMore } from '@material-ui/icons'`